# How to add MetaData when using create_device in Google IoT Core?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, iot

I am trying to add metadata during device creation. But unable to get the metadata structured.

Currently I am using python & nodejs client to implement the same.

```
metadata = {
    "name":"testdev"
}

return client.create_device(
    request={
        "parent": parent,
        "device": device_template
    },
    metadata =metadata)
```

I have also tried tuples but unable to get them working. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [create_device](https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudiot/2.0.0/iot_v1/services.html?highlight=create_device#google.cloud.iot_v1.services.device_manager.DeviceManagerClient.create_device) describes the type of `metadata` as `Sequence[Tuple[str,str]]` which isn't immediately helpful to me but confirms that your use of a dictionary *isn't* correct.

It's difficult to repro without creating a Project and enabling IoT, can you try some permutation of `[("name","tester")]`? I don't understand why it wants tuples there, but... that's what the SDK docs suggest.

The definitive source-of-truth for **all** Google's APIs is [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) and, for [Cloud IoT](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/cloudiot/rest/), for [devices.create](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/cloudiot/rest/v1/projects.locations.registries.devices/create), it suggests that [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/cloudiot/rest/v1/projects.locations.registries.devices#Device.FIELDS.metadata) is a map (i.e. dictionary)!?

> For Golang, [`Device`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/cloudiot/v1#Device), `Metadata` is a map too but, these Python SDKs are tried-and-tested too so there will be a good explanation.